# Prove: Let $Gal(f)$ acts transitively on $Z(f)$ if and only if $f$ is irreducible in $F[x]$

Tags: galois-theory, group-actions, extension-field

Can someone provide a proof for this, please? Particularly for the backward direction.

Let $F$ be a field.
Let $f(x)$ be a separable polynomial in $F[x]$.
Let $K/F$ be the splitting field of $f(x)$.
Let $Z(f)$ be the set of roots of $f(x)$ in K.
Then $G$ acts transitively on $S$ if and only if $f(x)$ is irreducible in $F[x]$.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See theorem 4.10(b) [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisappn.pdf). The link is to an expository paper by Keith Conrad. He has many others [here](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/), including some very nice ones on Galois theory, which you may find useful.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise it was that obvious...

Comment: @Potato: The link seems to be http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/galoisaspermgp.pdf now (theorem 2.9(b)).