# Automorphism of $\mathbb Q(\cos(2\pi/n))$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

How can you show that any automorphism $\xi$ of $\mathbb Q(\cos(2\pi/n))$ is defined by $\xi(\cos(2\pi/n)) = \cos(2m\pi/n)$ for $\gcd (m,n)=1$?

It's simple to see that multiplication and addition are preserved, so it must be a homomorphism. I just can't figure out how to show that it is bijective as well, which must be linked to the fact that $m$ and $n$ are prime to each other.

Comment: What is $Q(\cos(2\pi/n))$?

Comment: @R_D, $Q$ is the rationals, $Q(\alpha)$ is the smallest field containing $Q$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: Automorphisms of your field are restrictions of automorphisms of the cyclotomic field.

Comment: I think Kaj Hansen's way (implicit in Gerry's comment) is the way to do this. It might be possible to go via the route of 1) $\cos(2m\pi/n)\in\Bbb{Q}(\cos(2\pi/n))$: by trig identities there exists a polynomial $T_m(x)$ with integer coefficients such that $\cos mx= T_m(\cos x)$. 2)  If $mm'\equiv1\pmod n$ then using $T_{m'}(\cos(2\pi m/n))=\cos(2\pi /n)$ gives the reverse inclusion. 3) showing that $\cos(2\pi/n)$ and $\cos(2\pi m/n)$ are zeros of the same polynomial (modify the polynomial $T_n(x)$ to fit this). Proving that this polynomial is irreducible does not seem trivial though :-(

Answer (score 8):

Here's an indirect way of tackling the problem:

Let $F \subset L \subset K$ be a tower of algebraic extensions.  The set of $F$-isomorphisms of $L$ will simply be the set of $F$-isomorphisms of $K$ [restricted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restriction_(mathematics)) to $L$.  This is a consequence of the [isomorphism extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_extension_theorem): each isomorphism of $L$ extends to an isomorphism of $K$.  Note further that any isomorphism for $K$ is determined by its action on a set of [basis elements](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Field_Extension_is_Vector_Space), and if $K$ is Galois, then $K$ contains all of the Galois conjugates of all of the basis elements.  Thus, when $K$ is Galois, any automorphism of $L$ extends to an automorphism of $K$.

Here, we have a tower of fields $\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{Q}( \cos(2 \pi/n)) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$, where $\zeta_n$ is a primitive $n^\text{th}$ root of unity.  Since $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ is a Galois extension of the rationals (it is the splitting field for the associated cyclotomic polynomial), it suffices to find *its* automorphisms and restrict them to the intermediate field.  The automorphisms of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ are determined by their action on $\zeta_n$ itself.  Where can $\zeta_n$ be sent?  The minimal polynomial for $\zeta_n$ is $\displaystyle \Phi_n(x) = \prod_{\gcd(k, n) = 1 \\ \ \ \ 1 \leq k \leq n} \left( x - e^{2i\pi k/n} \right)$, and since [the Galois group of an irreducible polynomial acts transitively on its roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/336074/prove-let-galf-acts-transitively-on-zf-if-and-only-if-f-is-irreducibl), it follows that we can send $\zeta_n \mapsto \zeta_n^k$ for any $1 \leq k \leq n$ such that $\gcd(k,n) = 1$.

Applying Euler's formula gives $\zeta_n = \cos(2\pi/n) + i \sin(2\pi/n)$ and $\zeta_n^k = \cos(2k \pi/n) + i \sin(2k \pi/n)$.  Restricting the automorphism determined by $\zeta_n \mapsto \zeta_n^k$ to the field $\mathbb{Q}(\cos(2i\pi/n))$ gives the automorphism of that field determined by $\cos(2i \pi/n) \mapsto \cos(2i \pi k/n)$.

Comment: That makes sense. I was misunderstanding what ζ^k_n meant.

Answer (score 0):

A bit cleaner if you write $2 \cos \frac{2 \pi}{n}$ since
$$ 2 \cos \frac{2 \pi}{n} = \omega + \frac{1}{\omega}, $$ where $\omega = e^{2 \pi i / n}$ is a root of unity. Lehmer pointed out, in 1933, that $2 \cos \frac{2 \pi}{n}$ is an algebraic integer.

Comment: I've actually been trying to use that, especially since I already know the automorphisms for ω. I just haven't figured out how to use that to find the automorphism for cos. Everything I do ends up with cos^m(2π/n).

Comment: @Will, I suspect Kummer knew that $2\cos(2\pi/n)$ is an algebraic integer. If not Kummer, then Dirichlet, or Dedekind, or some other 19th century figure.

Comment: @Gerry  understood. It was late, and this 1933 reference appeared in a new article in the M.A.A. Monthly, Chebyshev Polynomials and the Minimal Polynomial of $\cos ( 2 \pi / n) .$ The other ingredient for me is finding Gauss method for cyclotomy in Cox, Galois Theory, then tables in  an 1875 book by Reuschle. https://books.google.com/books?id=wt7lgfeYqMQC&pg=PR1&lpg=PR1&dq=reuschle++tafeln+complexer+primzahlen&source=bl&ots=VGZFPrfUBn&sig=MlQ667PqXaQ9rAvLWkG3_F1rwsk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiIwtSvm9TQAhUJ-2MKHXJIA_kQ6AEIODAE#v=onepage&q=reuschle%20%20tafeln%20complexer%20primzahlen&f=false